# How to create an object copy from a pure abstract base class reference?

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that works for any derived classes in a certain hierarchy, without modifying the abstract class input parameter:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int val): m_i(val) { }
    virtual void add(int i) = 0;

    int m_i;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B(int val): A(val) { }
    B(): A(0) { }
    virtual void add(int i) { m_i += i; }
};

class C: public A {
public:
    C(int val): A(val) { }
    C(): A(0) { }
    virtual void add(int i) { m_i += i*2; }
};

int f(const A& base_class)
{
    // how to create a concrete copy of class base_class?
    base_class.add(5);
}
```

Here f() should work for both B and C, but I can't create a copy of the concrete class because I don't know the actual type, unless I use dynamic_cast.

Is there another approach to solve this problem or should just use dynamic_cast?

Comment: why does f() need to make a copy?

Comment: Note that the issue here isn't about abstract classes, but about base class references in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach commonly known as the [*virtual constructor idiom*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-ctors.html) is to define another virtual method for cloning the concrete class, make it virtual in the abstract base, and call it as needed to produce instances of the desired class without knowing its type:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int val): m_i(val) { }
    virtual void add(int i) = 0;
    virtual A* clone() const = 0; // Override in derived classes to return new B/C
    int m_i;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question why you even need to make a copy.

However, if you do, you could have a `clone()` method:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual A* clone() const = 0;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    virtual B* clone() const { return new(*this); }
};

class C: public A {
public:
    virtual C* clone() const { return new(*this); }
};
```

Comment: I need to make a copy because I can't modify the input const reference directly. I can't call add() on that parameter and I cant' change the function signature.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing `const A&` but `add` is not a `const` method if you take away the `const` modifier then this works:

```
int f(A& base_class)
{
    // how to create a concrete copy of class base_class?
   base_class.add(5);

   ///Need a return here
}
```

I am using `gcc` and the error that really tells you what is going is this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'A::add(int&) const'
  base_class.add(a);                                  ^^^^^  

no known conversion for implicit 'this' parameter from 'const A*' to 'A*'
                                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Based on your response the other option is make `m_i` `mutable` and make the member methods `const` like so:

```
class A {
  public:
    A(int val): m_i(val) { }
    virtual void add(int i) const = 0;

  protected:
    mutable int m_i;
};

class B: public A {
 public:
    B(int val): A(val) { }
    B(): A(0) { }
    virtual void add(int i) const { m_i += i; }
};

class C: public A {
  public:
    C(int val): A(val) { }
    C(): A(0) { }
    virtual void add(int i) const { m_i += i*2; }
};

int f(const  A& base_class)
{
    base_class.add(5) ;

    //Need a return here
}
```

Comment: I can't want to modify the input parameter.

Comment: @RobertKubrick `add` mutates the class so you can not pass it as `const` and call `add` as well. If there is another `const` function you want to call instead of `add` then that would work to.

Comment: @RobertKubrick unless you want to declare `m_i` as `mutable`

Comment: @RobertKubrick Added example w/ `m_i` as `mutable`